# Squishit keeps looking for AjaxMin version 4.48.4489.28432

Tags: squishit, ajaxmin

I have installed squishit version 0.9.8.2 with Ajaxmin 4.96.4941. The problem is that when I run the ASP.net site I get error

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.48.4489.28432, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
```

SquishIt.Framework.Minifiers.JavaScript.MsMinifier.Minify(String content) in c:\dev\urandom\SquishIt\SquishIt.Framework\Minifiers\JavaScript\MsMinifier.cs:31
   SquishIt.Framework.Base.BundleBase`1.MinifyIfNeeded(String content, Boolean minify) in c:\dev\urandom\SquishIt\SquishIt.Framework\Base\BundleBase.Rendering.Internals.cs:340
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +110
   System.Linq.d__16`2.MoveNext() +348
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +476
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
   SquishIt.Framework.JavaScript.JavaScriptBundle.AggregateContent(List`1 assets, StringBuilder sb, String outputFile) in c:\dev\urandom\SquishIt\SquishIt.Framework\JavaScript\JavaScriptBundle.cs:84
   SquishIt.Framework.Base.BundleBase`1.GetMinifiedContent(List`1 assets, String outputFile) in c:\dev\urandom\SquishIt\SquishIt.Framework\Base\BundleBase.Rendering.Internals.cs:333
   SquishIt.Framework.Base.BundleBase`1.RenderRelease(String key, String renderTo, IRenderer renderer) in c:\dev\urandom\SquishIt\SquishIt.Framework\Base\BundleBase.Rendering.Internals.cs:290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a problem with 4.96 at some point but don't remember exactly what.  Have you tried adding a binding redirect?

I'd recommend updating to 4.97.4951.28483 (or using the YUI minifier).

For the latter, somewhere in global.asax.cs (before you do any bundle rendering)

`Bundle.ConfigureDefaults().UseYuiForJsMinification()`